# How to redirect www to non-www on GoDaddy when using Firebase hosting

Tags: dns, firebase-hosting

I am unable to redirect `www.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`. I have tried adding an A record with subdomain `www` and IP address from firebase, but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You need to setup forwarding of your subdomain (`www`) as follows:

Goto GoDaddy's Manage DNS page and scroll down to forwarding, here is the configuration to set:

[image: GoDaddy add new subdomain forwarding]

Comment: A CNAME record will also solve the problem.

Comment: @ankush981 OP asked for a redirect. It's important for anyone reading this comment to note that a CNAME record is not the same as a redirect; each serves a different purpose.

Comment: @DarkMatter Agree. They are technically different things, but I mentioned it in case someone isn't aware of this possibility.